# xplode data in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, pandas-explode, first-normal-form

I got a table like this

[image]

Category is a multiple selection, the count simply is the number of occurrences. I want to tranform to this table

[image].

In python, i can use xplode function. But u want using formular or appscript in googlesheets to solve this problem. I try arrayformular, and split. But it's not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TOCOL(SPLIT(A2:A4,",")&"|"&B2:B4),"|"),"where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's worked. I'm really preciate!!